# Is there any downsides to preloading feature modules in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-module, ng-modules

I just learned about preloading feature modules in Angular via adding this line inside the `RootModules.forChild()` method inside imports in your root module.ts file:

```
preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
```

It seems to speed up my application! I am just wondering if there are any downsides to this or reasons why you would choose not to preload features modules.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is for people who visit a single url over a 4G connection that they'll be downloading your entire application over 4G, even when visiting only one url. Other than that, it only has upsides

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/network-aware-preloading-strategy-for-angular-lazy-loading-b883a0fbbaf0) explains how to implement a network aware preloadingstrategy

Answer (score 0):

Preloading is good for the modules which are to be visited by the user just after loading the application. Else, it just increases the size of the application to load and thus reduces performance. It's better to lazy load the component on the go.

Comment: Preloading doesn't increase the size of the application. It may download too many files/bytes when stable, while it simply isn't guaranteed the user will visit these pages